# Is it a listings package bug?

Tags: listings

I use listings package (the newest version 1.8b), but in the following case it doesn't work correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\begin{lstlisting}
lstlisting content
\end{lstlisting}
text

\section{Title}
text
\begin{lstlisting}
lstlisting content
\end{lstlisting}
text

\section{Title}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

There wasn't this problem in the previously versions. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug and a very old one.

The `lstlisting` environment does, at the end, `\let\if@nobreak\iffalse`, which is wrong because it's a local assignment, whereas the kernel command `\@nobreakfalse` does the job *globally*.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\let\lstlisting\relax
\let\lstlisting@\relax
\lstnewenvironment{lstlisting}[2][]{%
     \lst@TestEOLChar{#2}%
     \lstset{#1}%
     \csname\@lst @SetFirstNumber\endcsname
   }{%
     \@nobreakfalse
     \csname\@lst @SaveFirstNumber\endcsname
   }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\begin{lstlisting}
lstlisting content
\end{lstlisting}
text

\section{Title}
text
\begin{lstlisting}
lstlisting content
\end{lstlisting}
text

\section{Title}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be related to the way listings places its output if it is the first box after a section title (I didn't really investigate). You can work around this by placing a `\leavevmode` after `\section` and before `\begin{lstlisting}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\leavevmode
\begin{lstlisting}
lstlisting content
\end{lstlisting}
text

\section{Title}
text
\begin{lstlisting}
lstlisting content
\end{lstlisting}
text

\section{Title}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you your answer. The maintainer of listings package removed the \leavevmode command in the definition of lstlisting environment. But I don't understand why.

Comment: @hair-splitter most likely to enable more possibilities for the placement, increasing versatility. Did you check whether that is the change causing this? Because I didn't.

Comment: I'm not sure. But it works correctly with \leavevmode.