# Spooky action at a distance with lstlistings

Tags: listings

In the following, the change of color affects not only 'B' but also 'E'.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  A
  {
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=red}\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    B
  }
  C
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}
      Listing
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  D
  \begin{columns}
    \column{\textwidth}
    E
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm pretty sure it's the same bug as reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165159/lstlisting-directly-after-section-start-removes-margin-before-next-section) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489121/is-it-a-listings-package-bug): The workaround of adding `\leavevmode` before the listing works here too. However it looks like an interesting instance of the bug: How can `lstlisting` "take" a local color change from a group that has already been closed, and propagate it to the `columns` environment of another slide (and nowhere else)?

Comment: I get only a red A. Show your log-file. (Beside this: I doubt very much that a color problem is the same bug as some wrong spacing).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you can find the files in this Google Drive folder: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WCrwEjHu3l22KmSKYpm8-Sku6feCMwoz

Comment: texlive 2016 is old, we have 2019.

Comment: Indeed! So it seems this bug was fixed... Should I delete the question? I would still like to understand how this happens in the texlive 2016 version. Note that this question is about "how can this happen" rather than "how to fix it" (there was already a known workaround).

Comment: Well you can install additionally a texlive 2019, activate some tracing commands (e.g. \tracingmacros) and then compare the log-files.

Comment: note that any appearance that colour obeys tex grouping is due to extensive colour support  in latex and to aggressive aftergroup usage by the colour package, colour ignoring tex grouping is the natural state of things.